# Can tfspreview (visualstudio) publish to private IIS Web Application server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Is it possible to make TFS Service (tfs.visualstudio.com) **continuous integration build template** that will **publish directly to private IIS server** like it publishes on Azure?
What other settings should I specify in the build template for this to work?

Comment: I'm not TFS expert, but you shall use another build template - most probably providing your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want a project checked in on tfs.visualstudio.com be compiled and deployed to a private (on premise) webserver ? If you add an on premise build agent to the tfs.visualstudio.com tfs server, the buildserver can reach your internal webserver (otherwise it can't deploy to it). It's then a question of using the correct template and settings to deploy your webapplication like described in http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.nl/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html.

Comment: You don't need an on premise build agent. You can use IIS web deploy to provide access to your target server to VSO.

Comment: He talks about a private IIS server. Not an azure one.

Comment: yes and this (deploying from VSO to a dedicated IIS server) is entirely possible WITHOUT an on premise build agent. i.e. if the IIS server is exposed on the web - then this is possible. I see that if it's not exposed on the web this would not be possible, but it's not clear what the OP means when he says "private" I'd say he means not azure but some dedicated machine or VM in some data centre somewhere. If so... yes its possible I do it many many times every day without a custom build agent. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Deploying to a public reachable server can indeed be done without a onprem build server. However people who ask these questions usually can't reach this server from the internet.